How electrons are produced in Scanning Electron Microscopy (SEM)?
I am referring to thermionic emitter using tungsten filament, as a current is applied to the filament and transfer heat until sufficient energy overcomes the work function, then the electron are emitted. As this site illustrates further, there involves other interaction which promote electron emission.
From the book "Scanning Electron Microscopy and X-Ray Microanalysis" of Joseph Goldstein:

The grid cap is connected to the filament by a variable resistor. The emission current leaving the filament is replaced by an equal current to the filament
through this resistor. This generates a negative bias between the grid cap
and the filament. In Fig. 2.7 lines of constant electrostatic field potential
(equipotentials) varying from negative through zero to positive are plotted.
Electrons move toward positive potentials, so they leave the filament only
where positive electrostatic field lines meet the surface of the filament. The
bias voltage causes a high curvature in the equipotentials near the hole in
the grid cap, producing a focusing action on the emitted electrons


I am not quite apprehending the process that the "electrostatic field lines" affect the electron emission of the gun.

A calculation of work function for tungsten to thermal energy equivalent $kT$ gives 5 eV = kT --> $T = 58000$ K. The melting point of tungsten is 3695 K. The electrons are removed from the material by the application of a properly oriented external field, not by heating the filament to thermally eject electrons. The field pulls the electrons off the filament, and the field lines guide the electrons through the aperture with a kinetic energy toward the target sample. The principle to remove the electrons from the pointed tip is the same as applied in field emission microscopy. The tip is pointed to increase the field density at the surface of the tip. Heating the filament causes the number density of free electrons to increase. Doing so increases the available electrons to contribute to the emission current.

Well, heating sure helps.

@JonCuster Yes, but not as the OP suggests -- as the primary way to cause thermal promotion of the electrons to eject them from the filament.

It might have been my lack of uncertainty with the emission cause. However, if we turn back to the matter at hand, I'm a bit more concerned about what is going on as the current is applied to the system
